# Unit test base Controller OnActionExecutionAsync and OnActionExecuted methods

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, moq

I have a base controller which I set some common controller properties for in the `OnActionExecutionAsync` method, and then set some common viewmodel properties in the `OnActionExecuted` method
this is working fine, but I now need to write some unit tests for it. no tdd for me..

the code I have is :

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    //set some controller properties
    await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    //set some other viewmodel properties
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

the problem I have with the `OnActionExecutionAsync` tests, other than it being a right pain to mock the context, is that when the method completes, it automatically calls the `OnActionExecuted` method, and falls over as the `ActionExecutedContext` is null.
i am assuming i need to call `await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);`, rather than simply `await next();`? to continue with the pipeline, although having checked the `Controller` code in github, it seems the base implementation only calls `OnActionExecuted` when the result form the ActionExecutingContext is null [aspnet core controller on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs)
any idea how I can get my test to work without it jumping off to `OnActionExecuted`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're integration testing. When things get difficult to test, it's a pretty clear sign that you're far outside the bounds of unit testing and should step back and re-evaluate. If there's some functionality that you want to ensure works, create a method that encapsulates that functionality and then test *that*. You can safely assume that `OnActionExecutionAsync` and such will function as they are supposed to and call your method, as that functionality is already tested in the MVC codebase.

Comment: This comment is everything. I actually think I've come across it before when exploring the same issue as I've just been dealing with!

The key reminder here is that we're not testing the pipeline, but a single unit of code - so in my case, I needed to be sure to be mocking the data that would ordinarily be instantiated within the onActionExecuting function.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a lightweight delegate as the "next" item

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

var actionContext = new ActionContext(_httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor(), new ModelStateDictionary());

var actionExecutingContext = new ActionExecutingContext(actionContext, new List<IFilterMetadata>(), new Dictionary<string, object>(), controller: null);

var executedContext = new ActionExecutedContext(actionContext, new List<IFilterMetadata>(), null);

await actionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(actionExecutingContext, () => Task.FromResult(executedContext));
```